# Talend - Reading value from tHashImport component in Java application - HowTo?

Tags: java, mysql, talend

I am new in Talend and currently I am writing my first Talend job.

I am doing the following:

- Query one MySQL db table `(SELECT * FROM docs WHERE DocName = 'XYZ')` which will return few records using `tHashInput`
- Store these records in memory using `tHashOutput`
- Fetch these records from memory using `tHashInput`
- and log the records using the `tLogRow` component

I am running this Talend job from Java application like this:

```
FetchDocuments mySQLConnectorJob = new FetchDocuments();
mySQLConnectorJob.runJob(new String[]{});
```

And at the end I would like to fetch these records somehow in the Java application, for example with some method:

```
mySQLConnectorJob.getResultSet();
```

I know that we can store these records in the CSV file using the `tFileOutputDelimited` component and then to parse that file in the Java application to fetch records, but I would like to avoid using that file if it is possible.

My questions:

1. Do you know maybe how I can fetch records in the Java application and finish this task?
2. If my design on Talend job is not good, could you provide me some advice how to change it to be able to finish task?

Thanks,
Nenad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could store the records in an instance object of mySQLConnectorJob using tJavaFlex or tJava.  Then get those values from the instance object.

Comment: Hi @Chandra Prakash, thank you for your suggestion. I already looked at the code of the job and this query records set is stored in `rs_tMysqlInput_1` variable which is in scope of `tMysqlInput_1Process` method, so I don't know/see the way how I can put it in the some other object using tJava or tJavaFlex (but I was thinking in that direction also). **If you know how we can do it, could you please send me some small example how this can be done?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to store values from `tHashInput` component to the `globalMap` object and to fetch these values in the Java application.
So after the `tHashInput` component I put `tJavaRow` component. In the `tJavaRow` component I created a new `HashMap` and inside that map I put the db table record. After that I put that `HashMap` instance to `globalMap` in the same `tJavaRow` component.

```
//Instantiate metadata Map

java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> docMetadata = 
    new java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>();

//Fetch document metadata and put it in the Map

docMetadata.put("documentID", metadata1.DocumentID);
docMetadata.put("documentName", metadata1.DocumentName);
docMetadata.put("creator", metadata1.Creator);

//Put metadata in global Map

globalMap.put("docMetadata", docMetadata);
```

`metadata1` is the connection name from `tHashInput` component to `tJava` component. When I started the job in the Java application I fetched `globalMap` using Java reflection.